# Size of Qt QRadioButton able to get smaller, but not larger than default

Tags: c++, qt, qradiobutton

I need to make the size of all radio buttons in my application larger...however, I can only seem to make them smaller.

Using

```
"QRadioButton::indicator{width: 13px;height: 13px;}"
```

works...but only to make it smaller. When I try to go larger than 13px, all it does it make the area the radio button sits on larger, not the actual button itself. Is this some windows thing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make sure you are not exceeding the `maximumSize()` of the radio buttons. IF you need to increase it, call `setMaximumSize`()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can create two image resources for checked and unchecked radio buttons, you can use them like this.

```
QRadioButton::indicator
{
    width: 50px;
    height:50px;
    image:url(:/images/unchecked_radio.png);
}
QRadioButton::indicator::checked
{
    image:url(:/images/checked_radio.png);
}
```